# How to set minimum height for stacked bar (apexcharts, stackedbar)

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I want to show a table of ReactApexChart in a view, and I want to set it in a way that all is fitting the view.
It should show statictics of answers to specific topics, so there would be always just one line of chart with positive and negative answers.

However, I am unable to make it fit in less than 100 px, where for my needs without title, even 30px would most probably be enough.

I see there is transform applied on chart, could it be the reason?
How to make it work?

Here is the example:

```
  {/* <ReactApexChart
      options={this.chartOptions}
      series={this.chartSeries}
      type="bar"
      height="100px"
    /> */}
```

Here are my options and series

```
private chartOptions = {
  stroke: {
    width: 0
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false
  },
  chart: {
    width: "100%",
    stacked: true,
    stackType: "100%",
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  grid: {
    show: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: [""],
    labels: {
      show: false
    },
    axisBorder: {
      show: false
    },
    crosshairs: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    axisBorder: {
      show: false
    },
    crosshairs: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  }
};
private chartSeries = [
  {
    name: "Empty",
    data: [44]
  },
  {
    name: "Success",
    data: [5]
  },
  {
    name: "Error",
    data: [1]
  }
];
```

Comment: Isnt it because of the div style? div has a width of 100%, Will giving width 100px, height 100px work?

Comment: no, unluckily it does not.I tried it and did not work. I also found a comment later that it is preferrable not to touch height setting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a function for setting a height of that chart? So in one of my charts, i had to fix the size so that the page doesnt show any scroll. My chart option was like

```
chart: {
            height: yourFunctionForHeight(), //return only number 
            type: 'bar',
            stacked: true,
            toolbar: {
            show: true
            }
       }
function yourHeightFunction() {
     //logic that calculates height
     return number; //without attaching px to it
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that

```
height={data.length ? `${32 * data.length}px` : '100%'}
```